# Customizing twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i never used twitter Bootstrap 3 i have to use Modal in my HTML page.when a button is clicked modal should be used.i want to use least code from Modal.No CSS and typography from twitter bootstrap.can anyone please help how to get jquery plugin related to Modal ??

Comment: Have you take a look on Bootstrap modal? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0):

As instructed in http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Just to get a better understanding, you can see my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dr34t/). I use jQuery and bootstrap-modal.js without other css and typography.

First, make a modal divs structure, and hide it when the page load whether using your own CSS or jquery

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

hide it with a piece of jQuery

```
$('.modal').hide();
```

and let the button toggle visibility of the modal